# Confidence Interval of Coverage Probabilities

Tags: confidence-interval, coverage-probability

Does it make much sense to calculate confidence intervals for coverage probabilities?

For instance, if a CI coverage probability is estimated to be 0.80, does computing an exact 95% binomial confidence interval for the "true" coverage of (0.6823120, 0.8889842) (actually computed in R via binomial.test()) mean anything? That is, is such an interval "useful"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage of a CI is a binomial random variable, so yea I think it would make sense to have uncertainty estimates reported in a simulation study.

That being said, I if the CI is cheap to compute I think we can likely just run sufficiently many simulations so that the resulting simulation error is within some desirable tolerance.

I would probably only care about the first two digits of precision in a coverage probability, meaning if you ran 10,000 simulations the uncertainty estimates likely wouldn't add much.